# Is $S^\infty$ contractible? Does it have CW structure?

Tags: algebraic-topology

How can I prove that  $S^\infty$ is contractible? 
Is $S^\infty$ a CW complex?

Comment: see [here](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/93_back/s-infty) for some good discussion on proof ,and i think you can surely find it interesting

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/198/how-do-you-show-that-s-infty-is-contractible

Comment: George's link was really fabulous than mine ,please look at it,

Comment: In answer to your second question, $S^\infty$ is a CW complex.  Let $X^0=*\coprod *$, and then obtain $X^{n+1}$ from $X^n$ by gluing two copies (the two hemispheres) of $D^{n+1}$ to $X^n$.  Then $S^\infty\cong \operatorname{colim} X^n$.